# Inserted images don't appear

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word

I'm trying to insert images to a word document. All that shows is a fine lined box but no image. Any ideas?

Windows XP with Microsoft Word Home & School.

Comment: Try "Paste Special".

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the graphic and select Text Wrapping. My version of Word 2007 uses In Line With Text as the default, which does not show the graphic unless it is shorter (vertically) than the lines of the paragraph.

Try selecting Top and Bottom or a few other text wrap options to see if the graphic appears - look at the page above and below too in case Word threw in some funky measurements.